# How to delete Lookup columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, export, microsoft-access

I have a list with more columns in SharePoint Online 2010. When I am making the extraction to Access or Excel, I have some columns which do not appear in my list of columns I created. I can see them though in a view all columns.
I understood there are `Lookup` columns.

How can I get rid of these columns as I don't need them anymore ? (I think they were created when I was playing/learning how to make some workflows)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: List Settings:

[image]

Go to: Columns>search for any lookup columns (See under 'Type' column)>select & delete

[image]

Comment: The columns i am trying to delete do not appear in my list of columns.

Comment: Are the columns called 'Item Type' and 'Path'?  If so, Sharepoint always exports these to Excel.  They are not actually columns that can be deleted.  If they are related to workflows, then you could try deleting the workflows in order to get rid of these columns; do you still need the workflows?

Comment: The name of columns are "3" and "XXX" which i think i put them when created some workflows. I deleted all workflows , but the  columns still appear.

Comment: What happens if you try to modify the view?  Can deselect these columns to stop them showing up in your View?

Comment: in the view i can deselect them, but my issue is when making extraction to msaccess, they appear in the file. ( of if i link msaccess to Sharepoint, when the data is imported to msaccess , these columns appear )

Comment: It sounds like your issue only relates to Access rather than Excel.  I don't use Access, so can't help with that.  You could try posting a new question about Access.  You might like to post a question on either the Superuser Stack Exchange site, if you don't get an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

When you export a SharePoint list to Excel using the built-in functionality, it also exports two columns called Item Type and Path that OOB behaviour of the list. And if your export is routinely done then you can hide the columns by using connection with the workbook . [For you  reference](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/print-live-list-or-library-data-from-excel-workbooks-using-data-connections/)

Answer (score 0):

The lookup field also display in the excel file when you export SharePoint list to excel.

I suggest you provide more detailed information and screenshots for further research.

Or we can export SharePoint list to excel using Client Object Model(C#) to achieve it.

**Article**: [Export SharePoint online List all data to excel Programmatically using csom code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186633/export-sharepoint-online-list-all-data-to-excel-programmatically-using-csom-code)