# How to export SharePoint list to excel and save it in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, export-to-excel

I want to export sharepoint list in a excel and save it in a sharepoint list.I am able to save it in local.So I am looking to generate excel and  save the same in sharepoint list by csom c#

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the code provided in the following article to export the data from the SharePoint list to excel:

[Export SharePoint online List all data to excel Programmatically using csom code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186633/export-sharepoint-online-list-all-data-to-excel-programmatically-using-csom-code)

In addition, you can save the data in excel to SharePoint using the code provided in the following article:

https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/using-csom-to-import-csv-files-into-lists-in-office-365sharepoint-online/